# RxJS - improve branching of operations

Tags: rxjs

I'm using Angular, with its `HttpClient` class.
I need to differentiate a valid call (HTTP 200) from an error call (HTTP not 200 or custom response).
Currently I'm using this pattern:

```
const httpSource$ = this.httpClient.get<MyType>(url)
const valid$ = httpSource$.pipe(
    filter(result => result.code === 0),
    tap(() => this.logger.debug(...)),
    map(result => Result.valid(result.value))
)
const error$ = httpSource$.pipe(
    filter(result => result.code !== 0),
    tap(() => this.logger.debug(...)),
    map(result => Result.error(result.message, result.value))
)

return merge(valid$, error$).pipe(
    catchError(e => of(Result.error<FunReturnType>>(e.message)))
)
```

I'm on the right path? Am I overcomplicating (this might just be an if-else on the `map` operator)? Can this be further simplified?

Comment: this approch call twice your ajax request no ?

Comment: @Yanis-git currently yes. But that's something I'll solve

Answer (score 1):

i my opinion i suggest you to consider doing something like this :

*I assume Result.valid and Result.error are both static helper to transform api answer to consumable object over your app.*

```
httpSource$.pipe(
    tap(() => this.logger.debug(...)),
    map(result => {
        if(result.code === 0) {
            return Result.valid(result.value);
        }
        else {
            Result.error(result.message, result.value);
        }
    }),
    catchError(e => of(Result.error<FunReturnType>>(e.message)))
);
```

this will solve your twice call and be more readable for next developer i guess.

Comment: That was basically my situation "before". What if I need more complex logic? Probably the map clojure would become too big, and I'd prefer not having private "helper" functions

Comment: The double call could be solved with the share operator

Comment: i don't recommand you to use share operator because you will not be able to ask again your server (get fresh update for example) since we will always return answer from first call. About you map whitch grow again and again, you can just call static method as you already have or pipe many map step by step

Comment: What about the partition operator? Maybe it could simplify, and it solved the the multiple calls too

Comment: yes! good idea as well, if your real case is so heavy, you should go to this approch

Comment: Ok! Using partition I obtain something like this `const [val$, err$] = partition(...)(httpSource$)`. Do you think there is a way to modify the array values returned from `partition()()` before assignment? I would like to avoid "intermediate" variables

Comment: i am not sur to get what you try to acheive so far

Comment: hooow i get it now, partition return array so :  `partition(...)(httpSource$)[0] === val$` and `partition(...)(httpSource$)[1] === err$`

Comment: Wouldn't this call partition two times?

Comment: partition yes, original observable, no